# How to persist ALL changes made in the browsers Web Development Mode

Tags: web, persist

I *think* I have checked through all the potential extensions, please correct me if you know of one.

Many times people need/like to hack away at the websites they visit and of course we want to save these for later as well, even share them. My question is how can I do this easily directly in web developer mode? Is there no way? Where should I go to request it?

Most of the time we find it convenient when hacking at websites to directly use the native developer tools `F12` (default).

For example if I open up a web page I visit a lot in web developer mode and insert some custom changes to the DOM structure, the Styles, or the behavior of the former I  expect those changes to persist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I did is use the default web developer tools console `F12`->`console` There I edited the DOM via javascript, then I saved all my console input into a greasemonkey script.

Basically what needs to be done is export the console logs (since you visited that site) to a javascript (.js) file which is run every time the domain is run. I still think this has been done before otherwise i may make an extension.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine you have to search through google/firefox extensions library.  For instance this extension looks like it'll change and persist the CSS for a site.  I'd imagine there might be one that you can do this with the DOM and load your own JS unless you'd rather write your own.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en

Comment: If you are looking to do logic/dom changes this is not what you want but if you are looking to do style sheet changes this is what you want.

but thanks i still think i just didnt search well enough